# SharePoint 2013 Workflow move document to another library when the task ends

Tags: workflow, document-library, sharepont

I have a document library in SharePint 2013, what I need is a workflow that triggers when a new document is uploaded to the library and that workflow specifies the people that can comment and edit on that document, specifying the duration of the task. When the document is Approved, Rejected or when the time limit passes then the document needs to be moved to another library where there is only read access and no one can edit it anymore. How can I do something like that?